# $m_*(A) + m_*(B) \leq m_*(A\cup B) + m_*(A\cap B)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $m_*$ be an inner measure defined by $$m_*(A) = \sup\{ m_*(K): K \subseteq A, \ K \ \mbox{compact}\}.$$ Verify $m_*(A) + m_*(B) \leq m_*(A\cup B) + m_*(A\cap B)$ for any $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n.$
I see the proof of the analogous result for outer measure $$m^*(A) + m^*(B) \geq m^*(A\cup B) + m^*(A\cap B)$$ using measurable hull of $A$ and $B$ so I try to mimic the proof. However, I cannot find the analogous theorem about measurable hull for inner measure so I  try to establish the result for the inner measure, but not quite success.

**Measurable hull for inner measure** Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with $m_*(E) < \infty$. Then there exists a measurable set $F$ such that $F \subseteq E$ and $m(F) = m_*(E).$

**Proof** By the definition, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a compact set $P_k \subseteq E$ such that $$m_*(E) - 1/k < m_*(P_k).$$ Let $P = \cup_{n=1}^\infty P_n.$ Then $P$ is measurable and $P \subseteq E$. So $m_*(P) \leq m_*(E)$ and $$|m_*(E) - m_*(P)| = m_*(E) - m_*(P) \leq m_*(E) - m_*(P_k) < 1/k$$ for all $k$. So $m_*(P) = m_*(E)$. Since I do not know if $m^*(P) < \infty$, I cannot concludes that $m_*(P) = m(P).$

So there is no such result for inner measure ? So how should I prove the inequality ? Any suggestion ? (Is there a more elementary proof for either outer measure or inner measure that does not involve measurable hull ?)

Reference : If $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $P$ is measurable if for any $M \in \mathscr{L}_0$, $P \cap M \in \mathscr{L}_0$. In this case define $$m(P) = \sup\{m(P \cap M): M \in \mathscr{L}_0\}.$$ For $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$,$$M \in \mathscr{L}_0 \ \mbox{if} \ m_*(M) = m^*(M) < \infty.$$ In this case define $$m(M) = m^*(M).$$

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the exterior, or interior, measurable hull, although they both exist.

For the interior: take $U \subset A$, $V\subset B$, $U$, $V$ measurable. We have 
$$\mu(U) + \mu(V) = \mu(U\cup V)+ \mu(U \cap V) \le \mu_{\star}(A\cup B) + \mu_{\star}(A\cap B)$$ and now take the $\sup$ of LHS for all $U$, $V$ to get 
$$\mu_{\star}(A) + \mu_{\star}(B) \le \mu_{\star}(A\cup B) + \mu_{\star}(A\cap B)$$
It's worth noticing that for every measurable $M$ and $A$ subset of $M$ we have
$$\mu_{\star}(A)+\mu^{\star}(M\backslash A)= \mu(M)$$ so we see the link between the inequality for outer and inner measures.

Comment: Hey, can you explain why taking the sup for the left hand side solves the problem? Because as far as I understand taking the $ sup \{ 
 \mu(U) + \mu(V) : U \subseteq A , V \subseteq B  \}$ is less than $ sup \{ \mu(U) : U \subseteq A \} + sup \{ \mu(V) : V \subseteq B \} $ which is by definition $\mu_{*}(A) + \mu _{*}(B)$